# Как получить количество видимых меток на карте?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

На карте используется два `objectManager`, в одном метки, в другом полигоны. При изменении масштаба, когда на карте допустим видны 15 и меньше меток, показать полигоны.

Answer (score 1):

Для объектов в менеджере есть метод `getObjectState(<id объекта>)`, который позволяет узнать, отображается ли в данный момент объект. [Подробнее в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/#getObjectState?from=SO)